# Coq: Prove Inductive relation (vs Fixpoint)

Tags: coq, coqide

Is it possible to "convert" a `Fixpoint` definition for the `count` function:

```
Fixpoint count (z: Z) (l: list Z) {struct l} : nat :=
  match l with
  | nil => 0%nat
  | (z' :: l') => if (Z.eq_dec z z')
                  then S (count z l')
                  else count z l'
  end.
```

To an `Inductive` predicate (I have my first attempt bellow, but I'm not sure if it is correct)?
(This predicate is supposed to describe the relation between the function's *input* and *output*)

```
Inductive Count : nat -> list Z -> Z -> Prop :=
  | CountNil : forall (z: Z), Count 0 nil z
  | CountCons: forall (n: nat) (l0: list Z) (z: Z), Count n l0 z -> Count (S n) (cons z l0) z.
```

To find out if it's correct, I defined this Theorem (weak specification):

```
Theorem count_correct : forall (n: nat) (z: Z) (l: list Z), Count (count z l) l z.
Proof.
  intros.
  destruct l.
  - constructor.
  - ...
```

But I don't know how to complete it... Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relation is incorrect because it is missing the case for when the head of your list is not the `Z` you're looking for. E.g. there is no term of type `Count 0 [0] 1` even though `count 1 [0] = 0`. Add that, and while you're at it make the type more natural (order the arguments in the same way and also make `z` a parameter).

```
Inductive Count (z : Z) : list Z -> nat -> Prop :=
  | CountNil : Count z nil 0
  | CountYes : forall l n, Count z l n -> Count z (z :: l) (S n)
  | CountNo  : forall z' l n, z <> z' -> Count z l n -> Count z (z' :: l) n.
```

As for the correctness theorem, well, `count` is inductive on `l`, so probably so should be any theorem about it.

```
Theorem count_correct (z : Z) (n : N) (l : list Z) : Count z l (count z l).
Proof.
  intros.
  induction l as [ | z' l rec].
  - constructor.
  - cbn [count].
    destruct (Z.eq_dec z z') as [<- | no]; constructor; assumption.
Qed.
```

Do note that there's an automated mechanism to define `Count` and `count_correct` from `count`:

```
Require Import FunInd.

Function count (z : Z) (l : list Z) {struct l} : nat :=
  match l with
  | nil => 0
  | z' :: l =>
    if Z.eq_dec z z'
    then S (count z l)
    else count z l
  end.
  
Print R_count. (* Like Count *)
(* Inductive R_count (z : Z) : list Z -> nat -> Set :=
     R_count_0 : forall l : list Z, l = nil -> R_count z nil 0
  | R_count_1 : forall (l : list Z) (z' : Z) (l' : list Z),
    l = z' :: l' ->
    forall _x : z = z',
    Z.eq_dec z z' = left _x ->
    forall _res : nat,
    R_count z l' _res -> R_count z (z' :: l') (S _res)
  | R_count_2 : forall (l : list Z) (z' : Z) (l' : list Z),
    l = z' :: l' ->
    forall _x : z <> z',
    Z.eq_dec z z' = right _x ->
    forall _res : nat,
    R_count z l' _res -> R_count z (z' :: l') _res. *)
Check R_count_correct. (* : forall z l _res, _res = count z l -> R_count z l _res *)
Check R_count_complete. (* : forall z l _res, R_count z l _res -> _res = count z l *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation! But, since I'm kinda new to Coq, there something I don't understand - I know the syntax, but in `destruct (Z.eq_dec z z') as [<- | no]` that does `[<- | no]`mean? Is there any other way to write that?

Comment: `destruct (Z.eq_dec z z') as [<- | no]; constructor; assumption.` = `destruct (Z.eq_dec z z') as [yes | no]. + rewrite <- yes. constructor. assumption. + constructor. * assumption. * assumption.` Putting `<-` or `->` instead of a variable name in an `intro`-pattern rewrites according to that variable in that direction and then deletes the variable all at once. [Please see the manual.](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#grammar-token-or_and_intropattern_loc)

Comment: Thank you! I know what rewrite is but I haven't found anything on `yes` and `no`. Do they mean `yes` if `z==z'` and `no` otherwise?

Comment: They are just variable names. I named them `yes` and `no` because they are the possible results of `dec`iding `eq`uality. You could rewrite `destruct (Z.eq_dec z z') as [yes | no].` as `refine (match Z.eq_dec z z' with left yes => _ | right no => _ end).`

Comment: Yes, it's always better to name the variables, thank you for your explanation!